# How to create my own windows explorer

Tags: vb.net, windows-7

I'm trying to create a program where I can hold my own files and be able to put a password upon opening the program. Once I put the password in, I'd then be able to access, make changes, and open my files that I choose to put in there. Any ideas or links on how I can do this? Any help is greatly appreciated. I did try this, but I get UnauthorizedAccessException. I get it when it reaches:
 For Each mDirectory As IO.DirectoryInfo In mNodeDirectory.GetDirectories in TreeView1_BeforeExpand

```
                  Private mRootPath As String = "C:\Users"
Property RootPath As String
    Get
        Return mRootPath
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        mRootPath = value
    End Set
End Property

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim mRootNode As New TreeNode
    mRootNode.Text = RootPath
    mRootNode.Tag = RootPath
    mRootNode.Nodes.Add("*DUMMY*")
    TreeView1.Nodes.Add(mRootNode)
End Sub

Private Sub TreeView1_BeforeCollapse(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.TreeViewCancelEventArgs) Handles TreeView1.BeforeCollapse
    ' clear the node that is being collapsed
    e.Node.Nodes.Clear()
    ' add a dummy TreeNode to the node being collapsed so it is expandable
    e.Node.Nodes.Add("*DUMMY*")
End Sub

Private Sub TreeView1_BeforeExpand(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.TreeViewCancelEventArgs) Handles TreeView1.BeforeExpand
    ' clear the expanding node so we can re-populate it, or else we end up with duplicate nodes
    e.Node.Nodes.Clear()
    ' get the directory representing this node
    Dim mNodeDirectory As IO.DirectoryInfo
    mNodeDirectory = New System.IO.DirectoryInfo(e.Node.Tag.ToString)
    ' add each subdirectory from the file system to the expanding node as a child node
    For Each mDirectory As IO.DirectoryInfo In mNodeDirectory.GetDirectories
        ' declare a child TreeNode for the next subdirectory
        Dim mDirectoryNode As New TreeNode
        ' store the full path to this directory in the child TreeNode's Tag property
        mDirectoryNode.Tag = mDirectory.FullName
        ' set the child TreeNodes's display text
        mDirectoryNode.Text = mDirectory.Name
        ' add a dummy TreeNode to this child TreeNode to make it expandable
        mDirectoryNode.Nodes.Add("*DUMMY*")
        ' add this child TreeNode to the expanding TreeNode
        e.Node.Nodes.Add(mDirectoryNode)
    Next
End Sub
```

End Class

BTW, I did not write the above code, I tried it off a link I found

Comment: *I get UnauthorizedAccessException* ...at what point?

Comment: You should really focus on a single problem you are having and approach the question that way: your title doesn't reflect the question you are asking. With a little background scope present the specific problem you are having and the suspect code where the problem occurs. You should always give a link to code you have copied off the web so the author gets proper credit.

Comment: It would be helpful to know what version of Windows you are working with. XP doesn't have the administrative defaults in place that Windows 7 has.

Comment: I edited to specify where error is in code.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the reason for the idea, but in case; just a word of warning that this will not make your computer files any more secure.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible you don't have administrative privileges?

Perhaps you should try a different `mRootPath`
Adding folders to the c:\Users requires admin privileges.

Comment: Hey, I closed vs10 and reopened it as administrator

Comment: @Jordan: the code in the OPs sample does not add any folders. It is simply getting the directory infos. Maybe try using `Directory` static methods instead. Getting the `DirectoryInfo` may be performing some additional operations...

Comment: @IAbstract Yeah that's true.  Although even to open another folder in c:\users you may need admin permissions.  

Try using impersonation...LogonUser(..)
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/cpimpersonation1.aspx ..Example of how to do so.  
I am presuming that this is an access problem.

Answer (score 0):

To give your application administrator privileges, first go into your project's properties and click the `View Windows Settings` button in the `Application` tab. Replace the existing `requestedExecutionLevel` tag with `<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />`.